# i need to replace NaN with blank space where the operation fails in dax power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

The table is like the image:

[image]

I need to keep the NaN as empty but when I use IFERROR() and put blank() in the ValueifError it just deletes the entire row which I dont want. Is there any way to replace NaN with a blank space

I used the dax below:
oscar wins = SUM(Films[OscarWins])/SUM(Films[OscarNominations])

Answer (score 6):

Try using the DIVIDE function instead of '/' operator.
Ex: Test = DIVIDE(Col1,Col2)

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the case when denominator is 0 as below. This will simply check, if the denominator is 0, it will return BLANK(). Other case it will return the result from normal calculation.

```
oscar wins = 
IF(
    SUM(Films[OscarNominations]) = 0,
    BLANK(),
    SUM(Films[OscarWins])/SUM(Films[OscarNominations])
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely your `SUM(Films[OscarNominations])` is returning 0, resulting in a divide by zero.

For your `IFERROR` fix, right click on a field value in your visual and select "Show items with no data".

[image]

Alternatively, on error, return 0. It really depends on how you want your audience to interpret the data. In reality, it is Not A Number (NaN)...